# Transform Matrix for ECEF to site co-ordinates

Tags: matrix, geospatial, linear-algebra

I am given site co-ordinate systems having the following parameters:

- Projection Type (usually Transverse Mercator)
- Ellipsoid/Datum  (usually GRS80/GDA94)
- Central Meridian
- Central Scale Factor
- False Easting
- False Northing

and then need to programmatically convert a large number of points from ECEF into the site co-ordinate system, so ideally I'd like to use a transform matrix.

Wikipedia gives the formula for this transform matrix as:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/6/c/5/6c5e10c1708acc1663d618c2f3fecc98.png

But how do I calculate the parameters needed for this formula from the site mapping parameters I have been given?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this conversion is to first convert from ECEF to geodetic coordinates (latitude,longitude,height), and then to convert these to map coordinates (northing,easting,height). Each of these transforms is non-linear. However if the site is not too large and your accuracy requirements not too stringent, you could carry out the above transforms on a few dozen (say) points round the perimeter of the site, and then use these points and the original to find an affine transform that best approximates the map coordinates from the ECEF coordinates.

I've played around with this a bit and it appears that while it is possible to get the eastings and northings with fair accuracy (eg a couple of centimetres over a site within a circle of radius 10km and a 20m height variation over the site; but if the height variation is 200m the accuracy drops to 2 decimetres), it is not possible to get even fair accuracy on the height -- in the example the height could be ~8m in error. This is unavoidable, as a line of constant height in site coordinates will be close to a circular arc, and if you compute the greatest distance of the chord from the arc for an arc of length 20km and a circle of radius earth radius you get ~16m.